# Ajax call not working in Chrome for Android web app

Tags: android, google-chrome

```
net::ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE
```

Is the error I get.

It's just a standard Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: postLink,
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(postData),
    ...
```

I suspect there's nothing wrong with the call itself.

Here's why - if I run the page in Chrome for Android it runs fine. No problems at all.

If I add that page to the homescreen, then Android treats the page as a web app (which is fine too, because it is). But I think there's something about the way Android/Chrome treats web apps that is stopping the Ajax call from going through. In this instance, the error above occurs.

Anyone heard of this issue before, perhaps know of a workaround?

Comment: I am having same issue, web app works within browser using Ajax call, but as when i set to homescreen aswell it does not execute.  have you had any success?